# How To Update An Image In Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-uploading

I have a php page that upload image to a folder and the name is inserted in mysql table . Now I want to create a page that will update the picture and delete the old picture in the directory folder or replace the old with the new picture.

Here is the code which is not updating not the image or the other fields.

```
 <?php
// Start a session for error reporting
session_start();

// Call our connection file
require("includes/conn.php");



// Set some constants

// This variable is the path to the image folder where all the images are going to be stored
// Note that there is a trailing forward slash
$TARGET_PATH = "images/";

// Get our POSTed variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description  = $_POST['description '];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];

// Sanitize our inputs
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($price);
$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

// Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e.  images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];


// Here we check to see if a file with that name already exists
// You could get past filename problems by appending a timestamp to the filename and then continuing
if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
        $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";
        header("Location: updateproduct.php");
        exit;
}

// Lets attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{
        // NOTE: This is where a lot of people make mistakes.
        // We are *not* putting the image into the database; we are putting a reference to the file's location on the server
        $sql = "UPDATE products SET picture = '$image', description = '$description' ,price = '$price' ,name = '$name'  WHERE serial = '$serial'";


 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
        header("Location: updateproduct.php");
        exit; 

}
else
{
        // A common cause of file moving failures is because of bad permissions on the directory attempting to be written to
        // Make sure you chmod the directory to be writeable
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory";
        header("Location: updateproduct.php");
        exit;
}
?>
```

here is the form

```
   <?php require_once('Connections/shopping.php'); ?>
<?php
$colname_Recordset1 = "1";
if (isset($_POST['serial'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_POST['serial'] : addslashes($_POST['serial']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_shopping, $shopping);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = %s", $colname_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $shopping) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
  <form method="post" name="form1" action="updateupload.php">
    <table align="center">
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">Serial:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['serial']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>" size="32"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">Description:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['description']; ?>" size="32"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">Price:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['price']; ?>" size="32"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">Picture:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="picture" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['picture']; ?>" size="32"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update record"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I dont know much about php I followed a tutorial to the insert part and based on that I tried to do the update which wasn't part of the tutorial @Bono

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss the

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to work with files.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: oooh how I forget that I will try it and let u know

Comment: I addred the enctype="multipart/form-data" but it didnt work ,,, plz help

Comment: @user1084949 in this line "$image = $_FILES['image'];" why you have 'image' if the field name is 'picture'?

Answer (score 1):

The [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function might just be what you wanted

```
if (file_exists($PATH_TO_IMAGE))
{
       unlink($PATH_TO_IMAGE);            
}
```

Comment: @user1084949 you can find $PATH_TO_IMAGE from mysql table because you stored image path in the table. cheers :)

Comment: @Subail Sunny I store image name (product.gif) in the table not the path ... the picture it self is saved in folder called images.

Comment: @user1084949 all if all images are stored in the same folder, then $PATH_TO_IMAGE = $folderpath.'/imagename'; will do the work